# Click overlay marker in Google Maps with capybara-webkit

Tags: capybara, capybara-webkit

Is there a way to click a Google Maps overlay with capybara-webkit? What about Capybara using Selenium? I want to test the content of the info window once the marker is selected. I also want to test that there are *n* markers on the page.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do this too, have you been able to find a solution?

Comment: No unfortunately not. I got nowhere with it.

Comment: seconded. we have an entire team trying to get this figured out

Answer (score 0):

To test that there are n markers on the page:

```
expect(find('.gmap_container')['data-markers'].split('},{').count).to eq(n)
```

Comment: I am no longer working on this can anyone else confirm that this works and I will accept this answer?

Comment: Didn't work for me. tried `find('.gmap_container')` and it was not found. Could be something on my end though.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done, but requires a change to how you create your markers. You must instruct them to render as images rather than canvas elements:

```
new google.maps.Marker({
  position:  latLng,
  animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
  name:      business.get('name'),
  id:        business.get('id'),
  optimized: false, // <-- this is the stuff
  title:     business.get('name')
});
```

Then in your test, you can `find('div[title="Business\ Title"]').click`

If possible, you might want to consider doing this just for a test environment, but that's up to you and your needs.

Credit: http://blog.mojotech.com/selecting-google-maps-v3-markers-with-selenium-or-jquery/

Hope this helps!