# Testing Google Map Markers with Capybara and Selenium in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, selenium, capybara

I have a google maps page that searches an address and then shows markers that are within 100 miles. I am trying to test that my markers have a content window that pops up when clicked on using Capybara, Selenium, and Rails.

I am receiving an error saying "Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotInteractableError: Element  could not be scrolled into view" 
Does anyone know how to fix this or a better way to test the pop up content window for google map markers? Scrolling doesn't work in Google Maps, so I am assuming that's why this is occurring.

```
  it 'enters in an address for IN Adjusters', js: true do
    visit '/maps'
    fill_in 'address', with: '4511 W 200 S'
    click_button('Search')
    sleep(5)
    element = find('map#gmimap0')
    element.click
    expect(page).to have_content("Burke Eric")
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that technically the `map#gmimap0` element has a height of 0px so the drivers have an issue figuring out where to actually click.  If you were using Chrome with selenium, and the `map#gmimap0` element had a child with size (`area` element for instance) then you could do

```
find('map#gmimap0 area').click
```

and it would probably work, however I believe you're using Firefox with selenium which still won't work like that due to bugs in either geckodriver or firefox. Luckily there's a way that will work in either browser which is to specify to click with an offset. This causes selenium to not worry about element size and just clicks at a location on the page offset from the elements location.

```
find('map#gmimap0').click(x: 10, y: 10) # offset x an y within the size of the marker
```

Comment: I did change the x and y to 11 each in case anyone else reads this.

Comment: @chasedougherty `x` and `y` just need to  be chosen to place the click within whatever size marker you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using Capybara's `visible: false` property when finding the map marker:

```
element = find('map#gmimap0', visible: false)
```

That should allow you to call the `click` method, as long as the element is available in the DOM.

Thanks!

Comment: I thought that would work too! Unfortunately, I still receive the same error. I'm glad you mentioned it though because now I am thinking there might be a different issue.

Comment: Ah, good point - it looks like there may be an issue interacting with canvas elements. One possible workaround is to render the map markers as images instead:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41132330/2076253

https://www.mojotech.com/blog/selecting-google-maps-v3-markers-with-selenium-or-jquery/

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/marker#MarkerOptions.optimized

If that works, you might set the `optimized` flag to `false` for your test environment.

Comment: Specifying `visible: false` when testing an app is generally a terrible idea, and you can't click a non-visible element anyway.  Also in this case the error is coming from the `click` call so it has already found the element and `visible: false` would do nothing.